# error messages are not shown in django form. and how to solve this value error?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

error messages are not working in Django templates.

after add error code in html template it shows no error message in webapp when fields are empty and press on submit button. html5 error is "novalidate" in template.

ValueError at /signup/
The view blog.views.user_signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

forms.py

```
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm, UsernameField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import gettext,gettext_lazy as _

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password(again)',widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    
    class Meta:
        
        model = User
        
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email']
        
        labels = {'username':'Username','first_name':'First Name','last_name':'Last Name','email':'Email'}
        
        widgets = {'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),}
        
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    
    username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus':True, 'class':'form-control'}))
    
    password = forms.CharField(label=_('password'),strip=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'current-password','class':'form-control'}))
```

signup.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-sm-10">
    <h3 class="text-white my-5">Signup Page</h3>
    <form action="" class="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        
        {% for fm in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
        {{fm.label_tag}} {{fm}} {{fm.errors | striptags}}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        
        <input type="submit" value='Submit' class='btn btn-primary'>
        
        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <p> {{error}} </p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.

# home
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html')

# about
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html')

# contact
def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/contact.html')

# Dashboard
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/dashboard.html')

# Logout
def user_logout(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

# Signup
def user_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, 'Congratulations You have become an Author.')
            form.save()
        else:
            form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/signup.html',{'form':form})

# Login
def user_login(request):
    form = LoginForm()
return render(request, 'blog/login.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Can you put the code of your `view.py` file ?

Comment: i added views.py but now one more new error came

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle GET and POST request :

```py
def user_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, 'Congratulations You have become an Author.')
            form.save()
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

Please make sure to use POST method in your html :

```html
<form action="" method="POST" class="post" novalidate>
...
</form>
```

Comment: how to do handle GET and POST ? is my code is correct? why this error shown and why error messages not working ?

Comment: In HTML, you might need to include `method="POST"` in `<form>` tag as well.